# Files created with "sudo" only are accessible by user

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have a sudo user, and whenever I use sudo to create, move, or copy a file to any destination (even user's home dir) the file is only accessible by root with the following permission:

> -rw-------  1 root    root test.txt

I'd expect it to be readable by group members and others.
Where should I specify this? I don't want to change the permission manually.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you use the `-p` option to preserve the ownership permissions if you copied it for example?   You mention commands that can change permissions unless you specifically tell the system to preserve permissions

Comment: I just find out that the default permission for new file was -rw------- (umask 0077), I changed it by adding umask 0002 to .bashrc, and it's fine now. Thanks